# Variance of the MVUE for a geometric parameter

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find the variance of the MVUE (built with Rao-Blackwellisation) of the estimator of the parameter $p$ of success in a Geometric distribution counting the number of failure. It seams to me a basic question but I cannot find the answer.

To sum up: $(G_i)_{i=1..N} \sim \mathcal{G}(p)$ are $N$ iid Geometric random variables with probability law $P[G = k] = (1-p)^k p$. I have calculated using the exhaustive and complete statistic $T = \sum G_i$ that:
$\hat{p} = \dfrac{N - 1}{N - 1 + T}$ is the MVUE for $p$. Now I would like to know $var[\hat{p}]$.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: How did you compute $E(\hat p)$?

Comment: I didn't, but since I used Rao-Blackwellisation on the original estimator $R = 1_{G_1 = 0}$ I know it is unbiased

Comment: Sure, but it could be helpful to check this before embarking on the computation of the second moment.

Comment: ok to compute the expectation, one uses the property : $\binom{k + N - 1}{k} \dfrac{N-1}{N-1+k} = \binom{k + N - 2}{k}$. Finally the sum writes $E[\hat{p}] = p \sum_{t \geq 0} P(T_{N-1} = t) = p$ with $T_{N-1}$ a NegBin(N-1, p) RV